# How to redirect from index.php to index

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I struggled a bit with Apache's `mod_rewrite`, but finally managed to configure(yes) and understand it(maybe?).

When the user goes to `/index` they are showed the `/index.php` page and the browser's url is `http://example.com/index`.

The user can also go to `/index.php` and the browser's url is `http://example.com/index.php`.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index$ /index.php
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php
```

So my question is, how do I redirect a user from `/index.php` to only `/index` using only the server's configuration?

Comment: Who us your rewrite rules, please!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what you mean by this.

in .htaccess to remove the extension .php you can use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I do believe this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.php$ http://www.example.com$1
```

Should work for removing the .php

Maybe try that?

Comment: I am getting `Internal server error`.